# Навострить лыжи - зачем?

Tags: фразеология

"Навострить лыжи" означает собраться куда-то. Но интересует происхождение этой поговорки. Я не лыжник, но, насколько я знаю, лыжи не острят, наоборот, у них концы загнуты, чтобы не втыкались в снег.
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само слово *навостриться* означает - задать себе направление, наладиться, начать снаряжаться куда-то. Ну, а "лыжи" в таком выражении подчеркивают основную мысль : куда повернул их носками, туда твои лыжи и покатят, ведь как раз задом наперед на них невозможно двигаться.

> А. Ф. Писемский. Масоны (1880)
> Знаю и думаю тоже **направить к ней лыжи**; говорят, она дама очень обходительная.

Comment: А  носки  лыж  как  раз - острые.

Comment: Носки завсегда острее пяток. И нос корабля значительно более острый, чем корма.